# Magento create Default Price for all product

Tags: php, magento

Hello friends i want to set default price for all products.
I Developed the jewellery shop website. i want to set default price for all product like.

if client add price for product then it's ok. display that price on front side.

but the client is not enter any price in product then the product take default price automatically.

how can i do this please help.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with observer like

create an Observer.php for the event `catalog_product_new_action`

And in observer set default price like below

```
<?php
class Namespace_YourModule_Model_Observer
{

    public function initProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

            $product->setPrice(100); // SET YOUR PRICE HERE             
    }    
}
```

hope this will sure solve your issue.

Comment: this is also a good approach , if you want to set a price in future also for new products creation . But if you have set all products than you can go for below approach

Comment: i got error call undefined member function setPrice() thank for help.

Comment: that means your product is not loaded in `$product` object or please check your observer setting

Comment: Sorry this is not working with this event catalog_block_product_list_collection Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can set the product for all prices in admin 
go to admin -> catalog->manageproducts  and on the right hand side you can see the action dropdown  . First select all products and than click on action dropdown and select update attribute values and submit. Then you will see the price option and all other attribute options which need to be updated . Just check the attribute price and add fill your new value. and save . the prices for all the products will set with your new value.

thanks and let me know if you have still any question